# Should I enforce a C++ interface at runtime or compile time?

Tags: c++, oop

I found this in [Nmap's source code](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/blob/master/libnetutil/PacketElement.h#L185):

```
/** This function MUST be overwritten on ANY class that inherits from          
  *  this one. Otherwise getBinaryBuffer will fail */                          
virtual u8 * getBufferPointer(){                                               
    netutil_fatal("getBufferPointer(): Attempting to use superclass PacketElement method.\n");
    return NULL;                                                               
 } /* End of getBufferPointer() */
```

If `getBufferPointer` were pure virtual, any derived classes failing to implement it would be caught at compile time. Why would it be better to opt for a runtime error as opposed to one triggered by the compiler?

Comment: Emmmm `virtual void override_me() = 0;` ?

Comment: It's easy to do with abstract virtual functions.  It looks like they are supplying a default behavior that will let you know right away that you'll have to do better.  I don't know why they chose to do it this way.

Comment: @duffymo: now that I look at luk32's comment, I feel that it was a silly question. Anyway, why would it be better to cause an error in the runtime in this case?

Comment: @duffymo Seems counter-logic, unless `netutil_fatal` is some compile-time check, that gives some explanation. Or it's designed to make it "bypassable". The more interesting question, IMO, is what are the advantages of nmap's approach.

Comment: If you don't want your base class to be abstract, Nmap's version may be the only way. That is the only advantage of this method I can think of. Note that it's not the case here, as the `PacketElement` class does have a pure virtual method...

Comment: If you thought an answer resolved your question (mine or another's), please mark that as the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

One should never prefer a run time error over a compile time error, especially when the language provides an easier way to do exactly what you want which will also give a compiler error. In my 5+ years of C++ coding I have never encountered a reason to use your way to create methods.

Run time error = Many possible causes, and I need my own debugging statements to find it. Possibly need to run the program many times as well. In your case I may have other classes which fail to override the method, which may cause errors at some undefined point.

Compile time error = One cause, and my compiler tells me what's up.

Answer (score 1):

Just make it pure virtual i.e.

```
 virtual u8 * getBufferPointer() = 0;
```

so that any subclass derived from its parent class(PacketElement) should redefine it.

Comment: That was already answered by @luk32 in a comment to the answer. And the second part of the question?

Comment: sorry I didn't notice the update .. my internet is damn slow :( and @luk32 is very fast :)

Comment: @d33tah;Coming to second question: why would it be better to cause a runtime error as opposed to one triggered by the compiler?
It's just my view:

Compile time errors: 
It basically covers minimal things such as syntax and type checking etc..that means it will check whether basic prerequisites for a program to run are met or not.

Runtime errors:
In this case of abstract methods, during compile time compiler just can't make out who is actually calling that abstract method by just parsing the syntax  and it all depends one the client's input to the program.so it will trigger runtime errors.

Comment: @d33tah you have any comments regarding his 2nd question